# Remove all polylines in google maps

Tags: android, maps, polyline

My problem is that I have two array list from lat and lng and I drawing polyenes from the lat and lng ,when frescoFinal is true then I want to remove all the polylines on the map fragment .
Tried Polyline.setMap(null) but cannot find the method ,
Any idea here is the code below :

```
if (fresco==true  || frescoFinal==true  )
                    {
                            polyline = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                                .clickable(true)
                                .add
                                        (new LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                                         new LatLng(lastLat.get(i), lastLong.get(i)
                                        ));

                            polyline.setEndCap(new RoundCap());
                            polyline.setWidth(POLYLINE_STROKE_WIDTH_PX);
                            polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);
                            polyline.setJointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            polyline.setColor(COLOR_BLACK_ARGB);

                        if(frescoFinal==true)
                        {
                          //  polyline.remove();
                            frescoFinal=false; 
                        }
                        }
```

Comment: Can you rearrange your code a little bit, I'm having an issue reading it.

Comment: basically what is important if (frescoFinal == true) I want to remove the polylines that has been drawn. if is put Polyline.remove(); still doesn’t remove all the polylines that been drawn.

Comment: First `if(frescoFinal == true) ` is redundant, the best way to check if `frescoFinal` is `True` is `if(frescoFinal)`. No need to add the `true` keyword. Finally, I still don't understand your code, probably because of the way its formatted. Anyways, if the Polylines are in `Array`, simply loop through it and call remove on each Polyline.

Comment: Solved Basically created 
  PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                        Polyline polylineFinal;